# onBackPressed() [deprecation]

Tags: java, android

Метод кнопки назад устарел (я использовал его для перехода назад на предыдущую страницу )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Пробовал заменить `onBackPressed()` приведенным ниже кодом.

```
onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Искал тут  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72634225/onbackpressed-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative`
но не понял :(

Comment: Для штатного перехода на предыдущую активити `onBackPressed()` переопределять вообще не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        
        getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                // ваш код для перехода назад
            }
        });

        // пример программного нажатия на кнопку назад 
        View view = null;
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getOnBackPressedDispatcher().onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: А можно ли это использовать не в onCreate?

Comment: @ДмитрийСахно как бы да, но нет. теперь обработка кнопки назад подобна setOnClickListener - ее надо установить. т.е. выбор у вас сделать это либо в onCreate либо в onResume. а чем вам не нравится делать это в onCreate? есть какие-то доп условия?

Comment: Да пойдет. Большое спасибо_)